# Why wont my images load in my React Vite project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

**Public Folder>>**
leaves.jpg

**App.jsx:**

```
function App() {
return (
<img src="./public/leaves.jpg" alt "img" />
)
}
```

The image is showing up on my image-preview extension which usually indicated the path is correct, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. It doesn't return an error when I try to use this method. I also tried importing the image like: `import leaves from './public/leaves.jpg'` and plugging it in like: `<img src={leaves} alt "img" />`, but it was throwing an error that the file couldn't be found.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't need to reference './' a domain is parent, public is parent to that so /public is all you need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `public` folder gets served from the root (`/`), so you need just:

```html
<img src="/leaves.jpg" alt "img" />
```

[See docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory):

> You should always reference public assets using root absolute path - for example, public/icon.png should be referenced in source code as /icon.png.