# Images not loading Vite/React

Tags: reactjs, vite, tsx

So I'm seeing the exact same problem as listed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77138313/why-wont-my-images-load-in-my-react-vite-project) but I'm referencing the image in the way described in the answer (so it seems to me) but still nothing is loading at runtime.  Here is my code:

vite config:

```
const config = defineConfig({
plugins: [react()],
build: {
    outDir: 'dist',
    emptyOutDir: true,
    assetsDir: 'assets',
    minify: false,
},
base: '/static/',
mode: 'development'})
```

code snippet:

```
function Navbar(props: Props) {

return <div className="navbar-fixed">
    <nav className="nav-extended white">
        <div className="nav-wrapper white">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#!" className="title grey-text text-darken-1">Company Name
                        <img src="/logo.png" alt="logo" className="circle" />
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>}
```

I've got the following file structure /static/public/logo.png.  When vite builds the logo.png is located in the outDir: /static/dist.  So it seems i've placed the image in the correct location but the logo will not load in the browser.

[filestructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sXzi.png)

I have tried using "/logo.png", "logo.png" and nothing works.

My only thought is that the built .js/css files are in /static/dist/assets while the logo is in /static/dist.  so I tried using '../logo.png' out of desperation but that doesn't work either.

No matter what I try I always get a 404 error for the image.  The URL that the browser is reporting to not work is http://localhost:8000/static/index.html/drive/logo.png which is definitely not where the logo is located.  So I'm wondering if its a build error and Vite is not creating the path correctly or if I'm just completely off base with everything I'm doing.

Please any help would be great.

Comment: Show your folder structure.

Comment: my file structure is described in my post but I added a picture to help illustrate.